# Передать переменную в value

Tags: javascript

Привет.
Что-то совсем голова не варит. Как передать значение переменной в value поля input? 
Вот код. Как вместо value='1' поставить value='значению переменной marka_id?'

```
var marka_id = $("#marka_id option:selected").text();
$("#selectBoxInfo").append("<input type='hidden' value='1'><br>");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var marka_id = $("#marka_id option:selected").text();
$("#selectBoxInfo").append("<input type='hidden' value='" + marka_id + "'><br>");
```